# In modal unable to get chosen date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, adminlte

I am using admin lte date picker its by default date format is mm/dd/yyyy 
when i change date into dd/mm/yyyy format I unable to get right selected date,

Here js code that is used to call datepicker

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true
    });
})
```

I always getting this date 01/01/0001 12:00:00 A.M.on changing format, How can i get correct date in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Comment: Can you show me the #datepicker tag ?

Comment: Did you try with `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'`?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay 
yes , Tag :-  <input class="form-control validuser"   id="datepicker" name="DOB" placeholder="Date Of Birth" type="text"  />

Comment: @niteshkumarmodi ,why I am got down vote?it's work fine?

Comment: @niteshkumarmodi,I have attach  Run code snippet .Now to check its works fine?

Comment: In my code when i write  format : 'dd/mm/yyyy' working fine , i getting date in dd/mm/yyyy format , but when i receive this date on contoller it show 01/01/0001 , what can be issue for that ??

Answer (score 2):

Don't write `yyyy`, write only `yy` for year and not `format` use `dateFormat`
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

or you can do it by attribute `data-inputmask="'alias': 'mm/dd/yyyy'"`

```
<input class="form-control validuser" id="datepicker" name="DOB" placeholder="Date Of Birth" type="text"  data-inputmask="'alias': 'mm/dd/yyyy'" data-mask=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery Datepicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the `JQuery` script code just paste the code.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

For more Details refer this link:

[date-formats](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html)

Comment: dateFormat is not working by this it selecting by default mm/dd/yyyy format,
actually when i tested i chosen 09/08/2017 so it seems to me right , so when i chose another date like as 24/08/017 , it show again 01/01/2017 .. that is not right

Comment: This is working fine in code snippet beacause it is jquery ui datepicker, but i am using admin lte datepicker and that case it is not working

Comment: @niteshkumarmodi, where you download adminlte date-picker,maintain link